# Crash with NSTimer while handling HTTP Connections

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, nstimer

Peace , my eXercice is to make the application connect , send and receive data to remote webserver and this is every 10 Secondes so idea goes to work with NSTimer and adding it into a runLoop , but the connection is established only once and then then ( in the next 10 seconds ) the app Crashes . Here is my Code , THANK YOU for HELPING .

```
#define HTTP_CONTACT_TIMEOUT 10.0
@implementation HTTPEXERCICEAppDelegate


@synthesize window;
@synthesize HttpConnTimer;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  


self->HttpConnTimer = 
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:HTTP_CONTACT_TIMEOUT target:self selector:@selector(Contact:) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self->HttpConnTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

return YES;

 }


 -(void) Contact:(NSTimer*)ttimer { 

 NSAutoreleasePool *Pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 HTTP_Comm *HTTPClient = [[HTTP_Comm alloc] init];
 [HTTPClient CommunicateWith:@"http://someURL"];
 [HTTPClient release];
 [Pool release];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

very suspicious place is

```
 HTTP_Comm *HTTPClient = [[HTTP_Comm alloc] init];
 [HTTPClient CommunicateWith:@"http://someURL"];
 [HTTPClient release];
```

are you sure you've retained HTTPClient in CommunicateWith:?
It either should be retained or should not be used after that.

Also do not use together:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:HTTP_CONTACT_TIMEOUT target:self selector:@selector(Contact:) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self->HttpConnTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

because scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval... already added timer to runloop. Use only scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval... or timerWithTimeInterval... with addTimer...